# problems with listview using in viewpager?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

i want to add a single listview in four pages of  viewpager with different data for each page.
    Vector pages = new Vector();

```
pages.add(listAppStore1);
pages.add(listAppStore2);
pages.add(listAppStore3);
pages.add(listAppStore4);

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(AppsActivity.this,pages);
    vp.setAdapter(adapter);

    vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (position1==0) {
                 modifydata();
                                     myAppStore.setadapter(mStoreAdapter);
            } else if (position1==1) {
                modifydata();
                                     myAppStore.setadapter(mStoreAdapter);
            }else if (position1==2) {
                modifydata();
                                     myAppStore.setadapter(mStoreAdapter);
            }else if (position1==3) {
                      modifydata();
                                     myAppStore.setadapter(mStoreAdapter);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

and here is adapter class
    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

```
 private Context mContext;
 private Vector<View> pages;

 public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, Vector<View> pages) {
  this.mContext=context;
  this.pages=pages;
 }

 @Override
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


  View page = pages.get(position);

  container.addView(page);


  return page;
 }



 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return 3;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
  return view.equals(object);
 }

 @Override
 public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  container.removeView((View) object);
 }

}
```

i am getting error in logcat after force close is 
    The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. any idea please!!!!!
now i have changed it with four listview.... and it is showing only three pages!!!where is the fouth one? And if pagerviewer holds only three pages at one time how to remove the first one on fourth position and vice versa????

Answer (score 0):

you are adding different views in the same parent(container) in `instantiateItem` method..remove this line from the `instantiateItem()`

```
 container.addView(page);
```

Comment: firstly it was showing data for first page and goes crashing on sliding page... but now it is not showing any thing and also not force closing.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are using a single list view object for all the 4 times(View pager childs). But in this is not acceptable. You can't add a single view object more than one time.

And also ViewPager accepts only 3  childs alive at a time(Current visible , previous to current visible, next to current visible).

So, Better to create new listview object each time

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong assuming you are adding the same instance of `listAppStore` to `pages` ?

If no it is the possible cause of the error.

You should initialize your views directly in the adapter and not outside it. The adapter should be only provided with data that is passed to the view for the given position.